# Is there a way to run these two loops without duplicating code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme and i have a situation where on the main loop template (index.php) I need to some times run a custom loop. So it looks like this:

```
$the_qry = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'offset' => 4, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC',  'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged ) );

if ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : $the_qry->the_post();
```

but in other situations I need it to run the normal

`if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();`

I tried wrapping them in an IF like this:

```
    if ( $special_situation == true ) {
         if ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : $the_qry->the_post();
    } else {
         if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    }
    // output each post code
    endwhile; endif;
```

but of course it didn't work because the while isn't being closed inside the IF statement, so it doesn't work that way. The only solution I can think of is to do this:

```
if ( $special_situation == true ) {
         if ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : $the_qry->the_post();
         // output each post code
         endwhile; endif;
    } else {
         if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
         // output each post code
         endwhile; endif;
    }
```

But it seems silly to me because the `// output each post code` doesn't change, so I am duplicating a lot of code.

Is there a way to simplify this all?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put `// output each post code` in a function and call that function in each spot?

Comment: I did consider that too, but I was hoping I could just leave it all in one file and simply manipulate the if/while/the_post() part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $wp_query;
if($special_situation == true){
    $the_qry = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'offset' => 4, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC',  'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged ) );
}
else{
    $the_qry = $wp_query; //Sets $the_qry to default query
}
if ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_qry->have_posts() ) : $the_qry->the_post();
    // output each post code
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: I saw your first submission and I used that to get practically the same result as your last edit. The only difference is I moved the global inside the else {} part, as it isn't needed unless the special_sitution is false. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, I had misread the question initially. Sorry about that. Glad it pointed you in the right direction, though!